# Detect newly added items from a mutation request

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a frontend that wants to mark to users which items in a list is newly added (imagine a new to-do is added, and it is refetched and this new item is marked to show the user that it is "new").

I am thinking of using localStorage to somehow save the old state of the getToDoList result and once this API is being refetched, it will compare with the old and mark new to-dos as "new".

Is there a way for react-query to detect this for me? If not, is there a cleaner way to build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on react-query documentation, you can access to old data with context.

```
 useMutation(addTodo, {
   onMutate: variables => {
     // A mutation is about to happen!
 
     // Optionally return a context containing data to use when for example rolling back
     return { id: 1 }
   },
   onError: (error, variables, context) => {
     // An error happened!
     console.log(`rolling back optimistic update with id ${context.id}`)
   },
   onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
     // Boom baby!
   },
   onSettled: (data, error, variables, context) => {
     // Error or success... doesn't matter!
   },
 })
```